# How to convert an Optional to an OptionalInt?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have an `Optional` that I want to "convert" to an `OptionalInt`, but there doesn't seem to be a simple way to do this.

Here's what I want to do (contrived example):

```
public OptionalInt getInt() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(someString).filter(s -> s.matches("\\d+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt);
}
```

However, there's no `mapToInt()` method for `Optional`.

The best I could come up with is:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(someString)
    .filter(s -> s.matches("\\d+"))
    .map(s -> OptionalInt.of(Integer.parseInt(s)))
    .orElse(OptionalInt.empty());
```

but that seems inelegant.

Am I missing something from the JDK that can make the conversion more elegant?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While the code isn't more readable than an ordinary conditional expression, there is a simple solution:

```
public OptionalInt getInt() {
    return Stream.of(someString).filter(s -> s != null && s.matches("\\d+"))
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).findAny();
}
```

---

With Java 9, you could use

```
public OptionalInt getInt() {
    return Stream.ofNullable(someString).filter(s -> s.matches("\\d+"))
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).findAny();
}
```

As said, neither is more readable than an ordinary conditional expression, but I think, it still looks better than using `mapOrElseGet` (and the first variant doesn't need Java 9.

Comment: This is a neat idea. Also, my bad re `of` vs `ofNullable()`:. I over-simplified the example. It should have been `Optional.ofNullable()`. I've updated the Q and pruned your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I convert an `Optional<String>` to `OptionalInt`

```
OptionalInt lastSeenId = Optional.of("123").map(Integer::parseInt).map(OptionalInt::of).orElseGet(OptionalInt::empty);
```

Comment: Just to highlight the key "two-step" from `Optional<Integer>` to `OptionalInt`, since I believe this is the most concise on offer: `.map(OptionalInt::of).orElseGet(OptionalInt::empty)`

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no way to do it in more elegant way using standard Java API. I asked Paul Sandoz about adding `mapToInt`, etc., [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2015-September/035426.html)'s his answer:

Me:

> Isn't it a good idea to provide also a way
> to transfer between `Optional` types like `mapToInt`, `mapToObj`, etc.,
> like it's done in Stream API?

Paul:

> I don’t wanna go there, my response is transform `Optional*` into a `*Stream`. An argument for adding `mapOrElseGet` (notice that the primitive variants return `U`) is that other functionality can be composed from it.

So you will likely to have in Java-9:

```
return Optional.of(someString).filter(s -> s.matches("\\d+"))
     .mapOrElseGet(s -> OptionalInt.of(Integer.parseInt(s)), OptionalInt::empty);
```

But nothing more.

That's because JDK authors insist that the `Optional` class and its primitive friends (especially primitive friends) should not be widely used, it's just a convenient way to perform a limited set of operations on the return value of methods which may return "the absence of the value". Also primitive optionals are designed for performance improvement, but actually it's much less significant than with streams, so using `Optional<Integer>` is also fine. With Valhalla project you will be able to use `Optional<int>` and `OptionalInt` will become unnecessary.

In your particular case the better way to do it is using ternary operator:

```
return someString != null && someString.matches("\\d+") ? 
       OptionalInt.of(Integer.parseInt(someString)) : OptionalInt.empty();
```

I assume that you want to return the `OptionalInt` from the method. Otherwise it's even more questionable why you would need it.

Comment: I made the example as simple as possible, but I should have said that it's not as simple as an `== null` test - I have a `filter()` in there too, And yes, I'm returning it from a method. I'll update the Q

Comment: @Bohemian, updated the answer. Still there's nothing in `Optional` class which cannot be done using Java 1.0 constructs.

Comment: Again, the filter example is contrived - I tried to keep it SSCCE. My use case is not so simple that a ternary would work well. I'll give you the proverbial cigar though :)

Comment: @Bohemian, then you can always add some `if` statements, there's nothing wrong with `if`.

Comment: Removing `if` statements is why I converted to `Optional` in the first place! :)  FYI, I intend to wrap this up in a utility method that does the "conversion".

Comment: "With Valhalla project (hopefully to arrive in Java-10)" — Almost seven years later and with Java 20 in progress, this is still being developed.

Comment: @M.Justin haha, indeed! I edited the answer to remove outdated hopes :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you have any object and not just a `String`, you can temporarily go through a `Stream`:

```
public static <T> OptionalInt toOptionalInt(Optional<T> optional, ToIntFunction<? super T> func) {
  return optional.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty)
    .mapToInt(func)
    .findFirst();
}
```

This solution has the advantage to be a one-liner, meaning you can copy/paste the content of the method and just change `func` to whatever you want. The disadvantage is going through a Stream to achieve what you want. But if you want a generic one-liner, this is it.

If you want a utility method, you probably prefer to use the following:

```
public static <T> OptionalInt toOptionalInt(Optional<T> optional, ToIntFunction<? super T> func) {
  if (optional.isPresent()) {
    return OptionalInt.of(func.applyAsInt(optional.get()));
  } else {
    return OptionalInt.empty();
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer exists because other answers don't come from an `Optional` as the title asks, but rather construct one, and take some liberties with the title question that I don't take.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option that doesn't need to use a Stream and avoids compiling regex every time:

```
private static final Predicate<String> IS_DIGITS = Pattern.compile("^\\d+$")
        .asPredicate();

public OptionalInt getInt() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(someString)
            .filter(IS_DIGITS)
            .map(Integer::valueOf)
            .map(OptionalInt::of)
            .orElseGet(OptionalInt::empty);
}
```

Note that you need to anchor the regex because asPredicate() uses find() instead of matches().

Or if you're using Guava, you can eliminate the regex entirely and use their Ints class:

```
public OptionalInt getInt() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(someString)
            .map(Ints::tryParse)
            .map(OptionalInt::of)
            .orElseGet(OptionalInt::empty);
}
```