# Cannot flatMap Optional to OptionalInt (or other optional primitives)

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Why can this not be done?

```
Optional<IntSupplier> supplier = Optional.of(() -> 42);
OptionalInt result = supplier.flatMap(intSupplier -> OptionalInt.of(intSupplier.getAsInt()));
```

> java: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) `U` (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression `java.util.OptionalInt` cannot be converted to `java.util.Optional<U>`

Instead you have to add extra steps:

```
Optional<IntSupplier> supplier = Optional.of(() -> 42);
OptionalInt result = supplier
        .map(IntSupplier::getAsInt)
        .map(OptionalInt::of)
        .orElse(OptionalInt.empty());
```

Why is there no simpler way to do this mapping, and why cannot `flatMap` be used to change the kind of `Optional`?

Comment: `OptionalInt` and `Optional` share no hierarchy. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713973/getting-an-optionalint-from-optional

Comment: Sigh, SO search is so bad. Why could it not find that for me?