# How to convert Optional<Integer> to OptionalInt

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

I have an Optional< Integer > variable:

```
//es is an arraylist, rock is a class in the arraylist
var as = IntStream.range(0,es.size()).boxed()
         .filter(i->es.get(i) instanceof Rock)
         .max((l1,l2) -> comparator(es,(Rock)es.get(l1),(Rock)es.get(l2)));
```

In that case, I want to return an OptionalInt for my method:

```
      if (as.isPresent()) {return Optionalint.of(as);} //Obviously it is not working
      return OptionalInt.empty();
```

How can I convert Optional< Integer > to OptionalInt in that case?
BTW I found this question [How to convert an Optional to an OptionalInt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713973/how-to-convert-an-optional-to-an-optionalint) is not quite helpful in my case, when I do like:

```
Stream.of(as).filter(s -> s != null && s.matches("\\d+"))
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).findAny();
```

It will give me an error: The method matches(String) is undefined for the type Optional
Any idea to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Please explain clearly _why_ the linked post is not helpful. Show how you have made used of the linked post and _how_ exactly it failed to solve your problem.

Comment: Have you tried `return as;`, instead of `return OptionalInt.of(as);`, since `as` is *already* an `OptionalInt`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Optional::map` to map the value into `Optional<OptionalInt>` and then use `Optional::orElse` to return either it or an empty `OptionalInt.empty()`. I assume the method `comparator` works correctly:

```
OptionalInt as = IntStream.range(0, es.size()).boxed()
            .filter(i-> es.get(i) instanceof Rock)
            .max((l1, l2) -> comparator(es, (Rock)es.get(l1), (Rock)es.get(l2)))
            .map(OptionalInt::of)
            .orElse(OptionalInt.empty());
```

Now the variable `as` is an instance of `OptionalInt`.

However, you cannot use that instance in your second snippet because `Stream.of(as)` results in `Stream<OptionalInt>` and I am sure it is not what you want. This is just a copied snippet from the linked answer. Remember, the value it holds is a primitive `int`, not `String`.